# Forçar a abertura de uma pagina

Tags: php, html5

Seguinte, estou estudando CRUD com PHP e não consigo resolver um problema...
Como faço para  que o PHP abra uma outra pagina caso uma condição esteja verdadeira?

No caso é um login, onde após a verificação se login e senha estão certos, quero redirecionar o site para uma outra pagina.

```css
*{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
.cabeca{
 background-color: #006666;
 height:60px;
}

.corpo{
 height:600px;
 background-color: ;
}
.form1{
 height:70px;
 width: 40%;
 margin:0px auto;
 margin-top:200px;
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 padding:30px;
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
 <head>
  <title>N2</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 </head>

 <body>
  <nav class="cabeca">
  </nav>

  <section class="corpo">
   <div class="form1">
    <form action="" method="POST">
      Login <input type="text" name="login"><br>
      Senha <input type="password" name="senha"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="ok"><br>
    </form>
   </div>
  </section>

  <footer class="cabeca">
  </footer>
  
  <?php
   include("conexao.php");
   $login=$_POST["login"];
   $senha=$_POST["senha"];

   $l=mysqli_query($con,"select nome_user from user where cod_user=1");
   $s=mysqli_query($con,"select senha_user from user where cod_user=1");

   $resl=mysqli_fetch_array($l);
   $resS=mysqli_fetch_array($s);




   if($resl[0]==$login && $resS[0]==$senha){
    //abrir uma pagina caso a condição esteja verdadeira;
   
   }
   else{

   }
      
  ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar a função [header](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php) :

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

no teu caso :

```
if($resl[0]==$login && $resS[0]==$senha){
        header('Location: http://teu_dominio/tua_pagina.html/');
}
```

Comment: Vale lembrar que o `header` deve ser usado antes de qualquer _output_ do PHP, ou seja, antes de qualquer HTML,  `echo` ou `print`